# How to Capture Mobile API Requests in burp when Server side pinning is implemented

Tags: web-application, android, man-in-the-middle, public-key-infrastructure, burp-suite

I recently encountered a scenario where Mobile Application is generating CSR request, call a POST API request and in response, Ask Server for certificate. Server will respond with the temporary certificate and Mobile Application will use that certificate for further API communication to prevent MiTM. This certificate will change at every login request.

as you folks might have already figured it out, `SSL Unpinning` won't help here because even if client trust any certificate , server won't..

As part of security testing , I want to test this API request in Burp Suite but failed to do so because without that certificate server will respond with 500. I am familiar with `Client TLS setting` in Burp but for that we need PKCS12 certificate with password which we don't have. I have a public key of that request certificate which mobile application is sending but i don't know how to give that publickey to burp.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

You need the client's private key too (not just the certificate, which contains the client's public key).

You'll probably need some amount of client-side instrumentation (e.g., using [Frida](https://frida.re)) to obtain the private key. You can use instrumentation to dump the client key pair from memory at run-time, or it might be saved to disk in the app's private storage. Once you obtain the keys, you can use them to create a P12 file that you can load into Burp.

Note that you'll either need a rooted device or a modified APK to use Frida.